# Reconciling using background-size: cover while building a website from a psd file?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scale

When I use `background-size: cover;` it causes the image to scale larger to fit the screen. This scaling means the background image doesn't match the dimensions from the psd file I'm trying to replicate. How do I keep the responsiveness that `background-size: cover;` provides, while maintaining the exact measurements from the psd? Thanks a lot for any help.

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="bg-img"></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.bg-img {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/site-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(../images/site-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

?

Comment: This just makes the image even larger, far larger than `background-size:cover`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to have the background image be able to grow to the maximum 'natural' size of the source image and then not be scaled any larger, this would likely have to be achieved through some combination of media queries (testing both portrait, landscape and square window sizes at various sizes), CSS, or JavaScript.

You could consider using a `max-width` and/or `max-height` attribute, along with `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;`. This may yield acceptable results, though it may be that JavaScript is where you would need to look for the most reliable result.

Comment: I feared this. Thanks for the insight.